# Iterating through nested dictionaries and find the keywords in the value of dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyword

I have data in below format.

```
data = {"policy": {"1": {"ID": "ML_0", "URL": "www.a.com", "Text": "my name is Martin and here is my code"} "2": {"ID": "ML_1", "URL": "www.b.com", "Plain_Text" my name is Mikal and here is my code"}}}


keywords = ['is', 'my']
```

Here are few things I want to do with my data in python.

First to iterate over my dictionary and to find and count the keywords mentioned above in the value of "Text" both in "1" and "2" and last thing is to update the current dictionary with keywords counts (no of times keywords mentioned in "1" and "2" like below.

```
{"policy": {"1": {"ID": "ML_0", "URL": "www.a.com", "Text": "my name is Martin and here is my code", "is": "2", "my": "2"} "2": {"ID": "ML_1", "URL": "www.b.com", "Plain_Text: "my name is Mikal and here is my code", "is": "2", "my": "2"}}}
```

If anyone can help me, would be thankful.

Comment: Can you explain what qualifies as "keyword"?

Comment: The value assigned to *data* does not constitute valid Python. Presumably it's supposed to be a dictionary but its structure is broken

Comment: keywords are just list of words that I'm interested search and count in that dictionary i.e in the value of "Text" of both "1" and "2"

keywords = ['is', 'my']

Comment: Yes it was just typo mistake. sorry for that

Comment: If you just want to look for a specific structure, just do it. If you want to find certain keys no matter where they are, search this site for "python flatten"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter
import json  # Only for pretty printing `data` dictionary.


def get_keyword_counts(text: str, keywords: list[str]) -> dict[str, int]:
    return {
        word: count for word, count in Counter(text.split()).items()
        if word in set(keywords)
    }


def main() -> None:
    data = {
        "policy": {
            "1": {
                "ID": "ML_0",
                "URL": "www.a.com",
                "Text": "my name is Martin and here is my code"
            },
            "2": {
                "ID": "ML_1",
                "URL": "www.b.com",
                "Text": "my name is Mikal and here is my code"
            }
        }
    }
    keywords = ['is', 'my']
    for policy in data['policy'].values():
        policy |= get_keyword_counts(policy['Text'], keywords)
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "policy": {
        "1": {
            "ID": "ML_0",
            "URL": "www.a.com",
            "Text": "my name is Martin and here is my code",
            "my": 2,
            "is": 2
        },
        "2": {
            "ID": "ML_1",
            "URL": "www.b.com",
            "Text": "my name is Mikal and here is my code",
            "my": 2,
            "is": 2
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:** Using `|=` to merge dicts is a Python 3.10 feature. Should not be hard to google how to do it if you are using an older version.*

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm posting as answer sorry) First of all, I think your dict structure is not correct to begin with. Syntax does not seem correct

Comment: Oh sorry it was typo mistake.
```
data = {"policy": {"1": {"ID": "ML_0", "URL": "www.a.com", "Text": "my name is Martin and here is my code"} "2": {"ID": "ML_1", "URL": "www.b.com", "Plain_Text" : "my name is Mikal and here is my code"}}}
```